# Why do ListView items not grow to wrap their content?

Tags: android, listview

I have a rather complex ListView, with variable list item heights. Under certain conditions, I need to display an additional view in a list item, which is hidden by default (`View.GONE`). By enabling it (`View.VISIBLE`), the list item grows in height (or at least it's supposed to).

The problem:
Even though I declare the item's root layout to `wrap_content`, and each component in the item to `fill_parent`, the view I hide/show which is supposed to change the item's height is simply cut off at the bottom instead of its parent (the item layout) growing in height to fully display it.

Are there any gotchas related to ListViews and item layouts and item height which I may have missed?

**Some more observations:**

For testing purposes, I have now reduced the list item layout to just contain the root LinearLayout and an ImageView. When I set the LinearLayout height to e.g. `200dip` and the ImageView to `fill_parent`, I would have expected the ImageView to grow until it hits the `200dip` limit set by its parent.

However, the image will instead be only ever as tall as its bitmap resource (as if I had set it to `wrap_content`) and the whole list item will be of the same height (i.e. as if I had set it to wrap_content, too).

If however, I set the image height to e.g. `200dip`, then the list item will grow in height, and so will the item layout.

In other words, the `layout_height` of the list item layout is completely ignored, and so is any height value on ImageView other than a hard-coded pixel value.

Comment: HI.. Matthias 

Please provide me an working example . am also facing the same problem , but am not clear how u solved. the problem.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I managed to fix this, but I don't understand *why*.

As I mentioned, I had set the `layout_height` of the list item layout to `wrap_content` (since `fill_parent` is meaningless here, considering that a ListView is indefinitely tall).

However, I had set the `layout_height` of all views *inside* that layout to `fill_parent`. The problem disappeared when setting them to `wrap_content` instead.

This raises two other questions:

1) What are the semantics of a view asking to `fill_parent`, when the parent `wraps_content`? Which size request takes precedence?

2) How would I ever make a view fill a list item if `fill_parent` apparently doesn't work?

Thanks for your input guys.

Comment: Thx for that Matthias =) I had the exakt same problem. I had also set the layout_height to "fill_parent". I thought that was obvious. But right you are, when setting to "wrap_content" it solved the issue.
Weird...

Comment: ok, for some reason, I had a similar issue, but when I had  only one item in the list, then the whole list view would be too small from the first display. So when I grew the item size, the view wouldn't grow. I had to set the view to "fill_parent" to work. Now, I need to see what happens where I have loads of items in it.

Comment: For your first question: parent `wraps_content` and children `fill_parent` makes no sense. When android is calculating the space needed for layout, it travels to the parent node. The parent says it needs enough space to wrap its children, so android asks how much space its children will need. But its children has no idea, since they want however much the parent is taking up. In short: parent `wraps_content` conflicts with children `fill_parent`.

Comment: For your second question: `ListView` is made to display unspecified number of items, which is why it's scrollable. If you want to fill the screen instead of letting extra items be scrollable, I'd suggest using `LinearLayout` with weights, e.g. `addView(item, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 1));`. The items will now take up height proportional to the weights you assign them, while filling up the parent (provided the height of parent is specified).

Answer (score 34):

Try this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm

```
public class Utils {

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Where do you run this method so that it is after the child has been remeasured?

Comment: Nice.. But you need this to make the `params.height` tage a `px` value and not a `dp` value.. `int dpValue = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1)); //dp value
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        params.height = (int) Math.ceil(dpValue * density);//pixels value`

Comment: Where do you run this method so that it is after the child has been remeasured?

Comment: I think no needed call `listView.requestLayout();`, because method `setLayoutParams` already have same calling.

Comment: I have a problem i am checked  lenovo 5.5 it's work fine, and lenovo, samsung 5'' inch as  one field was not shown scroll as enable, nokia and redmi 5.5" inch as extra space adding listview at the bottom how do u solve.

Answer (score 21):

How are you inflating your rows?

If you are not using it right now, try using `LayoutInflater#inflate(layoutId, parent, false)` (where `parent` is the `AdapterView` supplied to `getView()` or `newView()`):

```
v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

Comment: Hi Mark, what are the semantics of supplying a root view to inflate(), but set attachToRoot to false? If the inlated view is not attached to rootView, what else is done with that view?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention: I pass null for rootView and false for attachToRoot. After all, the view is returned by adapter.getView(), which I expected takes care of adding it to the view tree.

Comment: Quoting from the documentation, "If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML." Otherwise, Android does not know how to attach the child to the parent, and so I think it uses a very generic LayoutParams.

Comment: Putting the parent worked for me and solved my row height issues

Comment: This worked! ```v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);``` (instead of what I had before, which was ```v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dashboard_card_item, null);
```

Answer (score 13):

The problems with layout could be caused by ScrollView to be the wrapper

I stumbled upon some note in 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

"...Note: You cannot use the value wrap_content for the android:layout_height attribute of a ExpandableListView in XML if the parent's size is also not strictly specified (for example, if the parent were ScrollView you could not specify wrap_content since it also can be any length. However, you can use wrap_content if the ExpandableListView parent has a specific size, such as 100 pixels."

I removed wrapping ScrollView and linear layout started working properly. Now its only to understand how to wrap the stuff to ScrollView. God help me

But anyway this is really weird behavior. I think that fill_parent is not really correct wording. When using heirarchyviewer tool I always see WRAP_CONTENT and MATCH_PARENT values for layout_width and leayout_height. So probably fill_parent is actually means match_parent which puts me in cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 1):

I use the "AbsListView.LayoutParams" to configure the width and height manually inside "Adapter.getView()".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom `View` in as the list item that is resizing, then you can take from PeBek's answer and do this when you construct the `View`

```
addOnLayoutChangeListener(
            new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View _, int __, int ___, int ____, int bottom, int _____, int ______,
                                           int _______, int old_bottom) {
                    final ListView list_view = (ListView) getParent();
                    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = list_view.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height += bottom - old_bottom;
                    list_view.setLayoutParams(params);
                    list_view.requestLayout();
                }
            });
```

When the `View` gets resized this callback method will me run and it updates the `ListView` height to include the change in height (delta bottom). The other values, if they prove useful for you are `view` (reference to the view), `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `old_left`, `old_top`, `old_right`, `old_bottom`. It works for expanding and collapsing the view.

**API 11** is required for `OnLayoutChangeListener`, don't know if there's a backward compatible way to do so.

Comment: Note: addOnLayoutChangeListener() requires api level 11

Comment: @larham1 noted, I must have just overlooked that when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: i would like to have a list inside my activity that fill all the screen either when the device is in vertical than in horizontal orientation.
I solve the problem using al Linear Layout that have height that have to fill_parent, and setting the height of the item in the list to 0dp while the layout_weight is setter to 1.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="@string/text_list_devices" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_paired"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/signup_t"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_status"
        />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/signup_t"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Print All Records"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_for_button"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to note about column alignment:

- The container LinearLayout element uses horizontal orientation and
  android:layout_width as match_parent.
- The TextView elements use android:layout_width="0dp"
- Each of the two TextView elements uses android:layout_weight="1" so
  that they use equal amounts of the available width.
- The android:layout_width property of each TextView element is set to
  "0dp".