# Android ListView chops off last item when using shape backgrounds

Tags: android, listview

I have an Android app that shows a ListView, where each element has a shape background. The problem is that the ListView seems to chop off the last element, not allowing space for the shape background ... I've looked on the web and here (e.g. [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661293/why-do-listview-items-not-grow-to-wrap-their-content)) but couldn't find an answer.

Here is an example with three items that would read 'age', 'attitude' and 'topic'. As you can see, it seems that the text is (mostly) all shown but the listview sizing did not allow for the shape background.

[image: ListView chopped at the bottom]

The listview would be defined as:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/section3_topic_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="7sp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
```

The item layout is simply:

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/font_dark"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
/>
```

In the above, I have also tried wrap_content for layout_height (no difference), but here I show a fixed size, hoping that this would fix the problem. Doesn't. The ListView height is set to wrap_content (but the problem is that its a tad too small, sadly).

The shape background is defined as

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffe4e8ff"
    android:endColor="#80f4fff0"
    android:angle="0"/>

<corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

In the List adapter, I see the shape background as basically:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_even);
```

Actually, there are different shapes for odd/even, but that is not at issue. The listview has fast scrolling on, and *if you scroll the list the last item does show in full*. Then the top item is chopped off, so the problem seems that the ListView hieght is just not computed correctly. Of course, if the list is longer than the screen there is no problem as then you have to scroll to get to the end anyway. But in a case where the content takes less than full screen you get the problem I am showing.

I have tried several other variations of height settings, to no avail and am out of ideas; I think that this sums up the problem --- anyone have suggestions? Is the shape background really the problem? Or not accounting for dividers?

UPDATE: Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/section3_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/cork2"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$Section3Fragment"
>

<ScrollView ...
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout ...
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/section3_l_s1_ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section3_l_list"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/section3_topic_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="7sp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/section3_topic_list_alpha"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="8sp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/section3_l_s2_ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section3_l_list"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/section3_author_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="7sp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/section3_author_list_alpha"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="8sp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Since we are getting deeper into this, here is an updated picture that shows both section3_author_list and section3_author_list_alpha. The alpha list is used to jump into the other one at this letter when its large, but that isn't important. Notice that both are chopped off at the bottom, which makes me think that the issue is not the overall size of the container that the listviews are in (here a horizontal LinearLayout) but something with the listviews themselves.

[image]

Ah, layout code is (this is the part for section3_author_list - similar for section3_author_list_alpha - not shown) :

```
    final ListView lv_main = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(resource_main);
    final ListView lv_alpha = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(resource_alpha);

    // list handling for the main
    final Section3StableArrayAdapter topicAdapter = new Section3StableArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.listview_custom, list_main);
    lv_main.setAdapter(topicAdapter);
 ...

  public static class Section3StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int mAuthorCurrentIndex = -1;
    private int mLastGetViewPosition = -1;

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public Section3StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        mLastGetViewPosition = position;

        //  Drawable shape = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_even);
        if(position == mAuthorCurrentIndex)
        {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selected);
        }
        else {
            if (position % 2 == 0)
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_even);
            else
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_odd);
        }

        return view;
    }


    public void setSelectedIndex(int k)
    {
        mAuthorCurrentIndex = k;
    }

    /*
    public int lastViewPosition()
    {
        return mLastGetViewPosition;
    }
    */
}
```

@cybersam = Thanks! I did see that one, but I have tried wrap_content for layout_height - didn't work

UPDATE2: It seems to be a function of not accounting for the dividerHeight in the ListView (set to 7sp and 8sp in section3_author_list and section3_author_list_alpha respectively). For one item there is no problem, as I increase the number of items more and more gets chopped. And if I set the dividerHeight to zero then nothing is chopped.

Comment: post your layout file, that will be more helpful

Comment: Have you tried setting your ListView's height to `match_parent`? By the way `fill_parent` is deprecated and even though it is exactly the same you should use the new constant `match_parent`.

Comment: This [link](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/setting-listview-height-depending-on-the-items/) seems to show how to programmatically change the ListView height, but I shouldn't have to do this, right? This one [link](https://gist.github.com/dokkaebi/4173446) shows an override for bindView() but that doesn't apply to ArrayAdapter I think

Comment: Here is the layout, i collapsed items that are of fixed size. The lists in questions are both of those in section3_l_s1_ll and section3_l_s2_ll - although one of these is always set to gone - I cross fade between them on selection. In one of these are two lists, before I showed only one of them, section3_topic_list, but the other one section3_topic_list_alpha has the same problem. Each of them are cut off at the bottom _in different places_ as they are not the same size. Code in next comment (I am limited in char count)

Comment: Layout code was added to first post ...

Comment: That was not your layout *code* -- it was just some more of the rest of your layout XML file. In any case, [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661293/why-do-listview-items-not-grow-to-wrap-their-content) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a bottom margin on the list item doesn't work (I recall reading that). But OK, the problem was the ListView not accounting for the dividerHeight. Even though the display did show the divider gap, it was not accounted for -- I am guessing because I had the divider set as `android:divider="@null"` when I change the ListViews like this, it works!

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/section3_topic_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
```

Note the divider is now set as transparent and not null. I hope all this helps others who might run into the same thing.

I submitted this as a bug: [Android Bug Submit](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187409). It seems to me that if the ListView is going to honor the dividerHeight spacing regardless of the divider setting then the total height should be correct.