# Last row of expandable listview not full view in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, expandablelistview

[image: Red mark Row view]

Here I uses view and there code as per given below.

```
 <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/tab_stone_info"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/styleBreakTabColor"
                                android:weightSum="9">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Type"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Type"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Shape"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Shape"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Qlty"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Quality"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Grade"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Grade"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Qty"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Qty"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Wt"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Wt"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_MMSize"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/MMSize"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_Setting"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/Setting"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stone_SettMode"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/SettingMode"
                                    android:textColor="@color/txtStyleBreakup"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                            </TableRow>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/layout_tab_stone_info_value"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                               >

                                <com.mindtech.ExpandableHeightListView
                                    android:id="@+id/listviewstone"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:divider="#00000000"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                                    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
                                     />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
```

And I uses epandablelistview as below class.

```
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }



    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {

//        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
//                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

//
//        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);


//        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
//                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
//        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
//        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
//        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();


        if (isExpanded())
        {

            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

I refer this question but did not get correct.
[Grid of images inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523609/grid-of-images-inside-scrollview/4536955#4536955)

[Gridview height gets cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut)

The main problem occur when first row height is not biger than second or other. if all row content length are same then no issues.

Comment: show listview content hold xml

Comment: please check i have added xml @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Show full xml please

Comment: too much view that can not show here.. issues in only expandable list and  expandable listview class

Comment: check there any padding from bottom or margin from bottom presents or not

Comment: no this is no margin or padding issues.. Its height issues of this line int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8406253/3758898

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting the LayoutParams for your ListView, modifying the height parameter, but you are never calling setLayoutParams to tell the view to use the modified height.  Try this:

```
if (isExpanded()) {

    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
//Add this line
    setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Also, I've ran into problems in the past with the onMeasure() method, not everything is measured when the framework calls that method.  You might try a [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html), where you can register a listener to be notified when the full view is laid out, like this:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
ViewTreeObserver vto;
if (layout != null) {
    vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();

    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            //Modify your LayoutParams here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one child, then it's better to use `ExpandableListView` or `RecyclerView` with different `layouts`. [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) is a complete and very good tutorial on using `ExpandableListView`.

While using `ListView`, it always adds height which is a bit less than the original one (or may be there's another case, but I don't know why. If someone knows, than kindly correct me). So you have to add some `dp's` height manually at the end.

I've done it by overriding `onDraw` method. Below is how I did it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    params = getLayoutParams();
    if (getCount() != old_count) {
        old_count = getCount();
        params.height = getCount() * (old_count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getHeight()+5 : 0);
        //I've added 5 pixels with each item to get proper height, you can alter it as per your need
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the height, but you are not passing it to the view.

Use this method, setLayoutParams(params);