# How to make transparent spaces between groups of items in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am basically grouping items to groups of two or one, something easily doable using Table in IOS and it's sections feature. I did it using different view types in android but had to use some hack to get it working because somehow Android is not using layout height from layout for space items.I fixed it by creating R.layout.list_section_space like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#600d47a1">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

but when it's specified like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#600d47a1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I think it is collapsed or something, and not visible..

I don't have problems, it works good, just empty space gets collapse when I don't use this layout hack and need to put there some comment to don't forget how it "works". Did not found any similar question either.

I am updating quastion so its more clear what I am achieving in my listview and why I use ViewType for spcace between items.

Imagine this list view types structure:

```
item
item
space
item
item
space
item
```

So I have two views one is item, one is space. Each has its view type, and space view layout gets collapsed because ListView is ignoring top layout_height argument evidently if I don't use my workaround. I don't see wow to use DividerItemDecoration thought.

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html?

Comment: I updated question, no I don't use RecyclerView either, as I am not aware that it can help to achieve what I do better.

Comment: What happens if you drop the `FrameLayout`?

Comment: @kalabalik I updated question...

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662611/3356270)?

Comment: @kalabalik it looks like thats solution, it would be nice to have it in this question as answer thought, because that question looks unrelated et first sight... The solution is then using layout inflater with parent as adapterView and attach to root false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the implementation of your adapter, I can only guess that (at least part of) the problem lies in the way you inflate your list rows. Make sure to inflate them, using

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)` where parent is the `AdapterView` supplied in the `getView()` method of the adapter.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662611/3356270) question.